# unittest.mock.call - is there a uniform way to verify call arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have operation `foo(p1,p2,p3)`. I mock it and want to verify whether it was called correctly. So I have a list of `unittest.mock.call` pseudotuples to check. But the same function call may appear in various forms:

```
foo(1,2,3)
foo(1,2,p3=3)
foo(1,p3=3,p2=2)
```

I'd like to check easily whether each parameter has correct value. I don't want to interpret all possible variants of `args` and `kwargs` stored in call object. The best way would be to get all arguments in one dict (as `kwargs`) regardless whether they were passed with keyword or not. Is it possible? Is there any way to make such task simpler?

Comment: Sounds like you may be reinventing [assert_has_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls)

Comment: you can also check [assert_called_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) which implies that it *will* take arguments.

Comment: Anthony: assert_has_calls doesn't do the trick call(1,2)!=call(1,p2=2)